# Is there a resizable SplitView or a Winforms SplitContainer equivalent in UWP?

Tags: uwp

Is there a control in the UWP framework, or open source libraries, which give the user control over the size of a [SplitView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/split-view) ? I want the functionality of ye olde WinForms [SplitContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy2Eg.png), which has a zone of 4-5 pixels where the user can hover with the mouse, drag and resize the two container zones.

This part of the app is going to be keyboard and mouse focused, so I don't care about touch functionality in this case.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Please accompany downvote with explanation of what rule I broke so I can improve.

Comment: I believe it's a good question, so I gave you a +1! :-) Unfortunately, the accepted answer seem not to address the splitview pane. Can you provide an example? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the UWP Grid splitter from the UWP tool kit http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/GridSplitter/